# Finding area under curve of implicit functions

Tags: integration

$y^3 - 3y +x =0 $

If I can express this as a function isolated for $y$ such that $y=f(x)$, I wanted to find area between $x=b$ and $x=a$

so,

$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx $

Now I do substitution

$ x= 3y -y^3=g(y)$ ( using implicit function definition)

$ dx = (3-3y^2)dy$

$ \int_{a}^{b} f( 3y-y^3) (3-3y^2 ) dy$

Now g(y) should be inverse of f(x), hence

$ f(g(y)) = y $

Is this method of finding area correct, or have I made a mistake when I said $g(y)$ is inverse of $f(x)$. If it's wrong, how would one find area of inverse functions?

Answer (score 2):

You're almost right, but you forgot to change the bounds of $a, b$ to $f^{-1}(a), f^{-1}(b)$ in your integration. You also need to be careful; this won't work on some intervals near $0$, as the function doesn't have an inverse on this domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can find area for its inverse function such as in this particular case :
$$ y= x(3-x^2)$$
that has roots at $ x=0, \pm \sqrt3, $ explicitly.